# Href to go to another page and load ajax on that page

Tags: asp.net, ajax, href, ashx

On **page A** I have these navigation link:

```
            <li>
                <a href="PageB.aspx" target="_blank" class="active">
                    <span>Option 1</span>       //<--I want to go to page B and load Ajax1
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="PageB.aspx" target="_blank">
                    <span>Option 2</span>       //<--I want to go to page B and load Ajax2
                </a>
            </li>
```

On **page B** I have these navigation link to load ajax on this page:

```
            <li >
               <a href="AjaxHandler/Ajax1.ashx?Type=Page&amp;Security=0">
                  <span>Ajax 1</span>
               </a>
            </li>

            <li >
                <a href="AjaxHandler/Ajax2.ashx?Type=Page&amp;Security=0">
                   <span>Ajax 2</span>
                </a>
            </li>
```

I want when I click **Option 1** on page A, it will go to page B and load **Ajax 1** on page B and same goes to **Option2**, I want it to go to page B and load **Ajax 2** on page B.

Right now the nav link on page A will only go to page B, and I need to click nav link on page B separately to load ajax on that page.

Can I achieve this via `href` on page A? Appreciate if anyone can help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You could pass a parameter to _PageB_ like `PageB.aspx?ajaxRequest=1` and process that parameter value when _PageB_ loads so that you can fire the corresponding ajax request.

Comment: Hi, u mean like, put it on Page A `href="PageB.aspx?ajaxRequest=1"`?

Comment: Yes, that's a way to do it. Then _Page B_ will receive that parameter and you should be able to work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thanks to vicpermir I figured it out.

**Page A:** Put parameter to pass to Page B

```
        <li>
            <a href="PageB.aspx?ajaxRequest=1" target="_blank">
                <span>Option 1</span>       //<--I want to go to page B and load Ajax1
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="PageB.aspx?ajaxRequest=2" target="_blank">
                <span>Option 2</span>       //<--I want to go to page B and load Ajax2
            </a>
        </li>
```

**Page B**: Add class to ajax handler

```
        <li >
           <a href="AjaxHandler/Ajax1.ashx?Type=Page&amp;Security=0" class="ajax1">
              <span>Ajax 1</span>
           </a>
        </li>

        <li >
            <a href="AjaxHandler/Ajax2.ashx?Type=Page&amp;Security=0" class="ajax2">
               <span>Ajax 2</span>
            </a>
        </li>
```

`$(document).ready(function (){` of `javascript` at **Page B**:

```
    function LoadAjaxOnPage() {
       let params = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams;
       let paramVal = params.get("ajaxReq");

       if (parseInt(paramVal) == 1) {
           document.getElementsByClassName("ajax1")[0].click();
       }
       if (parseInt(paramVal) == 2) {
           document.getElementsByClassName("ajax2")[0].click();
       }

    }
```

Basically what happen is, when page B load, it take the parameter passed from page A and auto click the `href` on Page B based on that parameter.